# Google Cloud Shell is putting files in one instance for two separate projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

[Newbie Alert]
I have gotten GCP up and running. I have two projects active. I have successfully gotten a sample webhook up/running with dialogflow in project one.

I now want to test something separate in a second project which requires uploading sample files and, as you'd expect, run a second set of commands and other things to work with that second project.

What's happening is that I'm getting everything needed for both projects showing up in the same place regardless of which project I start up the Cloud Shell. I can't run certain commands or overwrite one file over the other as it breaks projects.

I assume this means it is one instance per user but how do you have a project and her files/actions completely separate from another project.  I know this is something dumb I'm missing.

Thanks in advance

Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rick, you are correct that the instance of Cloud Shell is per user and not per GCP project.  To separate files intended for different GCP projects you should just use different subdirectories of your home directory.  To switch projects within Cloud Shell, you can use the 'gcloud config set project ...' command; the name of the currently selected project will appear in Cloud Shell's tab title and in the terminal prompt.

We are in the process of making the relationship between the selected project and the Cloud Shell session a little more obvious in the user interface.  Stay tuned for some changes in the coming weeks.

p.s. I saw that you also asked this using Cloud Shell feedback form, but I am answering here for the benefit of others that might have the same question.

Comment: Thank you for answering this.  I wasn't sure about the using feedback form so, also thanks for answering that.   Rick